# VSCode stops recognising Java projects

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

My vscode used to work properly with Java projects, but sometimes it just stops working.
It shows no project is found in the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + Shift + P` on Windows or `CMD + Shift + P` on Mac, run `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`.